# link error [LNK2019] showed up when trying to compile Cython code with C++ DLL libraries in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, compiler-errors, cython

1. I tried to call C++ functions in dll from Python.
2. I have successfully produced a C++ DLL (*.dll, *.lib and *.h) and I have test that the DLL library works if I try to call its api functions just from another C++ code. (it is working in C++)
3. However I am struggling to make a python wrapper around it.

I have spent over 48 hours on this so any kind of help/advice/hint/critics are greatly appreciated!!

I read most of the available docs about the related stuff online although I don't fully understand all of them. By tweaking some part of the code and compiling again, it smells like the issue is that the linker couldn't resolve external functions declared in the dll header file (*.h).

It is probably useful to know that I test the "connection" between the *.pyx and *.h is working because if I put fewer arguments when calling the api function in *.pyx, the error message will say the number of parameters is not consistent with that in the header. so the issue really is the interaction between the *.pyx and *.dll which should depend on *.lib. At least this is how I think.

Since I am not sure if the *.h file for *pyx should use "__declspec(dllimport)" or "__declspec(dllexport)", I tried both. Neither of them solved the issue.

In another word, it smells like the linker is not able to find where the definition of the api function (symbol) is in *.dll because even if I change the libraries arguments in setup.py (e.g. from libraries = ['libcds'] to libraries = ['nonexist']), the error msg is the same, which is "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CalcUpfrontCharge_API referenced in function blabla...

So I suspect that the setup file is missing some part to let the compilation know that it should look for the *.lib file and locate the definition in dll. Right now it seems it is ignoring the *.lib because as I said, even if I cross out the libraries argument entirely in extension(), I got the same error.

I also tried to build the pyd from source code (not dll) but also failed.

```
it is as simple as this  (updated CDS_API macro):
libcds.h
#ifdef CDS_EXPORTS
#define CDS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CDS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    CDS_API double CalcUpfrontCharge_API(
    char *expiries[], double rates[], double couponRate, double 
parSpread, double recoveryRate, char *today1, char *valueDate1, char 
*effectDate1, char *maturity
    );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


cdspricer.pyx
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: libraries = libcds
# distutils: include_dirs = .
# distutils: library_dirs = .

cimport numpy as np
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libc.string cimport strcpy, strlen

cdef extern from "libcds.h":
    double CalcUpfrontCharge_API(
        char *expiries[], double rates[], double couponRate, double 
parSpread, double recoveryRate, char *today1, char *valueDate1, char 
*effectDate1, char *maturity);


def CalcUpfrontCharge(vector[char *] expiries,
                  vector[double] rates,
                  double couponRate,
                  double parSpread,
                  double recoveryRate,
                  string today,
                  string valueDate,
                  string effectDate,
                  string maturity
                  ):
     some logic...

cdef double res = CalcUpfrontCharge_API(c_expiries, c_rates, couponRate, 
parSpread, recoveryRate, today1, valueDate1, effectDate1, maturity1)
return res

setup.py
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [
Extension('cdspricer',
          ['cdspricer.pyx'],
          # Note here that the C++ language was specified
          # The default language is C
          language="c++",  
          depends = ['N:\Trading\Python\ISDA\libcds.lib'],
          extra_link_args = [],
          include_dirs=["N:\Trading\Python\ISDA"],
          libraries=['libcds'],
          library_dirs=["N:\Trading\Python\ISDA"])
]

setup(
name = 'cdspricer',
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
ext_modules = ext_modules,
extra_compile_args=["-O3", "-Wall"],
include_dirs=[np.get_include()] 
)
```

Comment: Are you linking to the import library?

Comment: `__declspec(dllimport) double CalcUpfrontCharge_API(` should be `CDS_API double CalcUpfrontCharge_API(`

Comment: You need to define CDS_EXPORTS when building your dll otherwise it won't export your symbols. And don't define it when using.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you very much for your reply. you are right. I suspect the issue is I did not "link" to the import library, but how? I put library dependency in extension() and I explicitly say cdef extern from "libcds.h": double CalcUpfrontCharge_API in the *.pyx. how do I "link to the import library"? also, I see the libraries keyworld arg in extension is only controlling which *.lib to feed link.exe.

Comment: @drescherjm yes sir.. I think the dll is built correctly (the *.h file I used for building dll defined CDS_EXPORTS and therefore followed your advice and exported that function. I also test the dll by calling the exported function in another C++ code, successfully.. but you are right that if I don't define it when using, the value will be "_declspec(dllimport)" anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came back to answer my own question.

After 36 hours struggling with the build I finally made it to work on my Windows7 system.
As the Cython compilation with C/C++ DLL entails so many details and tricks, any of which is so critical that even missing one seemingly trivial step can lead to entire failure of the compile/link process, I will highlight all the error-prone pitfalls that I ran into and the solutions:

1. Your setup extension has to follow the shape like this:

```
    ext_modules = [
        Extension('cdspricer',
              ['cdspricer.pyx'],
              # Note here that the C++ language was specified
              # The default language is C
              language="c++",
              extra_link_args = [],
              include_dirs=["N:\Trading\Python\ISDA"],
              libraries=['cdslib', 'msvcrt', 'msvcmrt'],
              library_dirs=["N:\Trading\Python\ISDA"])
    ]

    setup(
    name = 'cdspricer',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    extra_compile_args=["-O3", "-Wall"],
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()]  # This gets all the required Numpy core files
    )
```

2. Importantly, if you always bump into the error: LNK2001/LNK2019, check to make sure that when you build your DLL, not only the header file has the __declspec(dllexport) in the front of the exported function declaration, but also the function definition in the source file should also follow __declspec(dllexport)!! It turned out that I was missing the prefix in the source file so the dll worked in other C++ projects but not in Cython!

```
#ifdef CDSLIB_EXPORTS
#define CDSLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CDSLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

    extern "C"
    {
        CDSLIB_API double CalcUpfrontCharge_API(
            char *expiries[], double rates[], double couponRate, double parSpread, double 
    recoveryRate, char *today1, char *valueDate1, char *effectDate1, char *maturity
        );
        CDSLIB_API double Test(
            double a
        );
    }
```

in the source code, you have:

```
    CDSLIB_API double Test(double a)
    {
        double b;
        b = a + 1;
        return b;
    }
```

**The Test function would work while the CalcUpfrontCharge_API wouldn't.**

3. Remember to wrap the pure C code functions' declarations with extern "C"
4. Very importantly, if your dll is built in x86 platform, it will never work with 64bit python! The best solution is to use Visual Studio (I used VC2015) where you can switch the solution platform from x86 to x64.

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into this issue using a plugin SDK Wizard that would create a plugin shell.  It would not build with only the shell and was getting this error.  It would be specific to this type of setup but the fix for me was that I was getting this warning:

```
warning C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format
```

After saving the files in the correct format, the unresolved external symbol error went away and I could build the solution.

While I know that this may not be the fix for your situation I am hoping that this may help somebody looking for an answer.